# RDS vs EC2 for a short time, testing oracle db?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have to develop a test application to be migrated in about 4 months to a full fledged IT farm. In that farm there will be an oracle DB so I want to have an oracle db too for my tests.

I know that, if I used RDS, I could setup a full licensed DB in few minutes. Anyway this comes with a cost for the next 4 months, costs I can't gain benefits from: I will not make use of security updates, I don't need data replication.

By using ec2, on the other hand, I can install a free Oracle XE edition. In this case I think the costs will be greatly reduced, anyway I can't estimate well how much time I will lose maintaing the db.

What is, according to your experience, the best solution for a short lived database?

Comment: What maintenance do you think you would need to do with a temporary, dev database? Not much, if anything, I would guess.

Comment: Alternatively you could install something locally. Oracle has made the effort [to become Docker friendly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=oracle+12c+docker).

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce your RDS costs by stopping the database instance when it is not in use. You can also use a small instance type to reduce costs.

See: [Amazon RDS Supports Stopping and Starting of Database Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/)